# Reconnect broken VHD chain programmatically

Tags: c++, c, windows, hyper-v, vhd

If there is a broken VHD chain (for example the parent VHD was modified, that's why the child no longer mounts), there's a way to fix it by using Hyper-V "Reconnect" feature. How do I do the same programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found a solution. One needs to open the VHD with `OpenVirtualDisk` using `OPEN_VIRTUAL_DISK_FLAG_NO_PARENTS` flag. Then call `SetVirtualDiskInformation` with `SET_VIRTUAL_DISK_INFO_PARENT_PATH` passing the same path as it had before. This will update the parent unique ID and allow to mount the chain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [AttachVirtualDisk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/vdssys/nf-vdssys-attachvirtualdisk), but I'm not sure if that's what you are after with regards to VHD chains.

Comment: No, Attach actually fails because of broken chain. I need a way to fix it. I tried using SetVirtualDiskInformation, however it doesn't seem to have an option to set the unique identifier.